# Execute one PHP file from within another - without modifying paths

Tags: php

I have two PHP files (NOT in the same directory) and one properties file, like so:

```
a.php
-----
<?php
echo "one";
include("/path/to/b.php");
echo "three";
```

and

```
b.php
-----
<?php
$num = file_get_content("b.properties");
echo $num;
```

where `b.properties` has `two` in it.

Since `a.php` and `b.php` are not in the same folder, the `include` in `a.php` causes the properties file not to load properly.

How do I go about fixing this?  Note that I cannot modify `b.php` or `b.properties` or obviously this would be a trivial question.

Comment: Can you `a.php` to the same folder as `b.php`? I'm not sure if I understand well what your problem is. When you write a question about an error, __always__ include details of the error. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: You can't do what you want without modifying the path specified in `file_get_contents` in `b.php`. This is the problem with using relative paths. The arbitrary constraints you're creating around this problem lead me to believe that it's contrived and most likely an [X/Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) which aren't very welcome on StackOverflow.

Comment: You could add the directory of b.php to the php include directive. Then the path wouldn't matter so much, although I don't understand why you can't edit the path... http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php

Comment: `a.php` is a web-served page, while `b.php` is not in the webroot and needs to stay that way.  The only way it can be hit is if `a.php` calls it.

Comment: Not in the web root but is the path relative to the web root consistent? Try using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "../path/to/b.properties");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP provides function [chdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) for changing PHP's curernt directory.
I think you can change PHP's current directory to the folder of b.php just before include b.php and set it back after include.

```
a.php
-----
<?php
echo "one";
chdir('/path/to');
include("b.php");
chdir(__DIR__);
echo "three";
```